# Ambiguous preposition of time

Tags: prepositions, time, subordinate-clauses

I am learning English, and would like to know if this sentence means A or B:

***I knew that you went there yesterday.***

A. You went there, and I knew it yesterday.

B. You went there yesterday, and I knew it.

Thanks. It would be great if you can point me to a online article about that-clause and prepositions.

Comment: A would be better expressed as _I knew yesterday that you went there_.

Comment: It can mean either.  Depends on context and how the words are stressed in speech.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous, the context would make it clear. However there is another alternative meaning which is "You went there yesterday and I knew that at the time you went". This means that the sentence is even more ambiguous than it first appears. Out of interest if you said "I _know_ that you went there yesterday" that would not be ambiguous because the verbs "to go" and "to know" are in different cases. Is the sentence any less ambiguous in your language?

Comment: I would assume that "yesterday" modifies " you went there" because of its proximity. Naturally, modifiers are placed next to the term being modified to avoid ambiguity. However, this may not be the case. As others have said, context or stress can be key elements to interpret the sentence correctly.